# open application and send a mail with hyperlink (to visit my site) in python

Tags: python, html-email

how to insert a hyperlink as a message in email to visit my site?

My application is made by **Python**2.7 with own framework I am sending mail by using the fallowing method.

```
def process_email(self,email_id,reson):
    Emp_ID = email_id
    message = reason
    message += '<a href="localhost:8080">click me to visit</a>'
    self.sendmail(to_user=Emp_ID,subject="Testinghyperlink",message=message)
```

But in email i am receiving it has raw html code as: `<a href="localhost:8080">click me to visit</a>` instead of click me to visit. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is not valid Python, the double quotes `"` are not correct.

Comment: In addition to what @LutzHorn says, you should also set the header correctly. If the Content-Type header isn't 'text/html', I very much doubt a major email client would be inclined to perceive it as such.

Comment: dono why i am getting -1 for this question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By using  Escape sequencing /" for double quotes

```
> I changed this line of code. html_message='<a
> href=\"localhost:8080\">click me to visit</a>'
```

[Reffered link](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)

Answer (score 0):

did not test but this should work

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

Emp_ID = email_id
html_message='<a href="localhost:8080">click me to visit</a>'
self.sendmail(to_user=Emp_ID
html_content = MIMEText(html_message, 'html')
message = html_content   
self.sendmail(to_user=Emp_ID,subject="Testinghyperlink",message=message)
```

Comment: What is this line about: `self.sendmail(to_user=Emp_ID`?

Comment: By using above code i received mail as >From nobody Fri Apr 08 13:04:41 2016 Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii" MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit click me to visit

Comment: Emp_id = email_id( attaching mail id to a variable Emp_id ) and sending it via sendmail function. Mail sending properly

Comment: is the link clickable?